# Organizing a one-to-one relationships for checksums

Tags: django

**Django==1.11.6**

I'd like to collect checksums for uploaded files. 
I have done it via GenericRelation. This is clumsy.
Because it is one-to-many relationship whereas a checksum is definitely  one-to-one.

**Could you help me understand whether this can be rewritten as a one-to-one relationship case?**

```
@receiver(post_save, sender=ItemFile)
@receiver(post_save, sender=Image)
def save_file_checksum(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    """
    Save a ckecksum for a file.
    """
    checksum = get_checksum(instance.file.path)
    existing_checksum = instance.checksum.first()
    if existing_checksum:
        existing_checksum.checksum = checksum
        existing_checksum.save()
    else:
        FileChecksum.objects.create(content_object=instance,
                                    checksum=checksum)

class ItemFile(models.Model):

    file = models.FileField(blank=False,
                            max_length=255,
                            upload_to=get_item_path,
                            verbose_name=_("file"))
    checksum = GenericRelation(FileChecksum)    

class Image(models.Model):
    file = models.ImageField(blank=False,
                                   verbose_name=_("Image"),
                                   max_length=255,
                                   upload_to=get_sheet_path)
    checksum = GenericRelation(FileChecksum)


class FileChecksum(models.Model):
    content_type = models.ForeignKey(ContentType,
                                     on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    object_id = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    content_object = GenericForeignKey('content_type', 'object_id')

    checksum = models.CharField(blank=True,
                                null=False,
                                max_length=255,
                                verbose_name=_("checksum"))

    def __str__(self):
        return "{} {}: {}".format(self.content_type,
                               self.content_object,
                               self.checksum)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make the GFK unique in FileChecksum.

```
class FileChecksum(models.Model):
    ...
    class Meta:
        unique_together = ('object_id', 'content_type')
```

This means that there can be only one FileChecksum for each combination of object_id and content_type.

**Edit**

I'm proposing just having OneToOne from both models to FileChecksum. There's no reason this wouldn't work; the only downside is that there isn't an easy way to get from FileChecksum back to the Image or ItemFile models, but you've said you don't care about that.

```
class ItemFile(models.Model):

    file = models.FileField(blank=False,
                            max_length=255,
                            upload_to=get_item_path,
                            verbose_name=_("file"))
    checksum = OneToOneField('FileChecksum')

class Image(models.Model):
    file = models.ImageField(blank=False,
                                   verbose_name=_("Image"),
                                   max_length=255,
                                   upload_to=get_sheet_path)
    checksum = OneToOneField('FileChecksum')


class FileChecksum(models.Model):
    checksum = models.CharField(blank=True,
                                null=False,
                                max_length=255,
                                verbose_name=_("checksum"))

    def __str__(self):
        return self.checksum
```

Comment: I don't like GenericForeignKey in this case. It is by definition a one-to-many relationship. You suggested some improvement to my code. Thank you.   But can anyhow it be replaced with a one-to-one relashinship?

Comment: Do you actually need the reverse relation from FileChecksum to the Image and ItemFile models? If not, you could just have a OneToOneField from both to FileChecksum.

Comment: I don't need any reverse relation. What I need is just somehow keep checksums. I still can't catch your idea. Could you amend you answer and show what to do?

Comment: Daniel Roseman, the problem I can' solve: we have two classes here: ItemFile and Image. I can organize an abstract parent class for them. But it will be abstract. And then when making migrations I'll get: general.FileChecksum.object: (fields.E300) Field defines a relation with model 'FileMixin', which is either not installed, or is abstract.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification. I have to try. Seems promising.